# Google Sheets apps script running every 5 minutes but pauses over night

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google apps script that is suppose to run every 5 minutes, however I've noticed that every night at around 11pm, it pauses and it won't start running again until 7:55am. (GMT)

Does anyone know why it would stop running overnight?

[image]

Comment: may be it exceeds available [quota](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)

Comment: I thought about that but it will send me a failed email if that happens.. I'll check my logs..

Comment: This isn't a programming question, it's an operational issue.  It might be a better fit for the [Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) site, or the [Google Apps Script group](https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769)

Answer (score 0):

Found out that my urlFetchApp was using up my quota like iJay said.

I found out by adding in a logger of everytime the script runs, it would add a timestamp.

Now optimised by urlFetchApp so hopefully it will run!